# how to call a js function into seperate div blocks to update a number

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an achievement tracker that when you click a checkbox it will update a number on how many you have completed in that section. But how I have it implemented now the number only updates on one of the div blocks.

## HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>Endings</h2>
          <p><span id="achievement-complete">0</span> / 2</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li id="achievement_7_0">
            <div class="card-content">
              <input type="checkbox" id="item_7_0" class="sum" value="1" />
              <label class='strikethrough' for="item_7_0">
                Ending 1
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="achievement_7_1">
            <div class="card-content">
              <input type="checkbox" id="item_7_1" class="sum" value="1" />
              <label class='strikethrough' for="item_7_1">
                Ending 2 
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="heading">
          <h2>All Achievements</h2>
          <p><span id="achievement-complete">0</span> / 1</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li id="achievement_8_0">
            <div class="card-content">
              <input type="checkbox" id="item_8_0" class="sum" value="1" />
              <label class='strikethrough' for="item_8_0">
                All Achievements
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
```

## Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
  total = document.getElementById('achievement-complete');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].onchange = function () {
    var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
    total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + add
    // console.log(add);
  }
}
```

Here I would like it to call a js function in each div block with class="card-body" and update the span with class="achievement-complete" with the new total of achievements completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your markup in a container element you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to capture event from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. Just attach one listener to that container rather than many listeners to many elements.

Then you can get the `checked` status from the element that fired the event, find the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) element with a `card-body` class, and use that to find the its child element with the `achievement-complete` class (note: this is a change to your markup where you've used `id` - ids must be *unique* in a page).

Then grab that element's text, coerce it to an integer, and update it - adding one if the `checked` status is `true`, and subtracting one if it's `false`.

```js
// Cache container element and add a listener to it
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {

  // Check that the element that fired the event
  // is a checkbox
  if (e.target.matches('[type="checkbox"]')) {
    
    // Destructure the checked attribute from the checkbox
    const { checked } = e.target;
    
    // Find the closest element with a `card-body` class
    const card = e.target.closest('.card-body');
    
    // Use that to find the local "achievement" element
    const achievement = card.querySelector('.achievement-complete');
    
    // Get and coerce its total to an integer
    let total = Number(achievement.textContent);
    
    // Update the text content with an new total
    achievement.textContent = checked ? total += 1 : total -= 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <section class="card-body">
    <h2>Endings</h2>
    <p><span class="achievement-complete">0</span> / 2</p>
    <ul>
      <li id="achievement_7_0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="item_7_0" class="sum" value="1" />
        <label class='strikethrough' for="item_7_0">
          Ending 1
        </label>
      </li>
      <li id="achievement_7_1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="item_7_1" class="sum" value="1" />
        <label class='strikethrough' for="item_7_1">
          Ending 2 
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="card-body">
    <h2>All Achievements</h2>
    <p><span class="achievement-complete">0</span> / 1</p>
    <ul>
      <li id="achievement_8_0">
        <input type="checkbox" id="item_8_0" class="sum" value="1" />
        <label class='strikethrough' for="item_8_0">
          All Achievements
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: Thank you so much dude! This problem has been kicking my butt for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].onchange = function () {
    var cardBody = this.closest('.card-body');
    var total = cardBody.querySelector('.achievement-complete');
    var checkboxes = cardBody.querySelectorAll('.sum');
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
      count += checkboxes[j].checked ? 1 : 0;
    }
    total.innerHTML = count;
  }
}
```